# Python - How to change date format in CSV file?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, datetime

I have data frame (df) in Python looks like this,

```
   date        acc_num      activate_time 
2017-03-10      11101    2017-03-10 12:13:30
2017-03-11      11102    2017-03-11 13:57:49
2017-03-12      1103     2017-03-12 14:28:05
```

Before I export the data frame into csv file, I used `pd.to_date` to change the date format for columns *'date'* and *'activate_time'*. Then I exported the data into csv file,

```
file_name = str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")) + ".csv"

df.to_csv(file_name, index = False, data_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

However, the date time format of column *'activate_time'* in CSV file are `10/03/2017 12:13:30PM`, `11/03/2017 13:57:49PM` and `12/03/2017 14:28:05PM`

Comment: Are you opening the CSVs in Excel? If so I believe that's just how Excel is representing them. You should be able to change how they are represented using Excel's formatting.

Comment: @bernie Thank you for the comment. Yes, I opened the CSV file in Excel. But I have several CSV files so changing the date time format in Excel will be very time-consuming.

Comment: If your end result is to be in Excel why not use `df.to_excel(file_name,index=False)`?

Comment: @bernie Since I need to upload the data to SQL database in CSV file. I'll try to look around other way to do that. Thank you.

Comment: Try to look at the [`.to_sql`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) method.

Comment: What do the dates look like if you open the CSV file in a text editor like Notepad, and not Excel? As long as the data is correct it doesn't matter what they look like in Excel; when it gets imported into SQL it will look a different way, too.  SQL just needs to have valid formatted dates to be able to import them.

Comment: @PeterTirrell Thank you, Peter! I opened it on TextWrangler and the date time format is correct.